# Finding the maximum contributer variables by applying the SVD - should the absolute values be used or just the maximum value?

Tags: clustering, svd

**My question:** When doing SVD analysis, you can extract the maximum contributors to each component from the V matrix - does the sign of the the component matter?

**Background**

I'm currently enjoying the Coursera class on [Data Analysis](https://class.coursera.org/dataanalysis-001/class/index) by Jeff Leek. It's a great course for filling in my knowledge gaps. In his lectures on *clustering* he proposed that one way to use the SVD is to find the most important principal components, and then look at which variable contributes the most to that component by choosing the maximum row-value from the corresponding column in the V matrix. My problem is that he focuses on the maximum value instead of the absolute maximum.

### Update: Simulating a pattern

*I guess the following simulation answers my question but I would appreciate some feedback*

To create a possible scenario I've tried to simulate a pattern where there are a few columns completely random.

Here is the simulation code:

```
set.seed(12345); 
dataMatrix <- matrix(rnorm(400),nrow=40)
colnames(dataMatrix) <- 
  c(paste("Pos.3:", 1:3, sep=" #"), 
    paste("Neg.15:", 4:5, sep=" #"), 
    paste("No pattern:", 6:8, sep=" #"),
    paste("Pos.15:", 9:10, sep=" #"))
for(i in 1:40){
  # flip a coin
  coinFlip <- rbinom(1,size=1,prob=0.5)
  # if coin is heads add a common pattern to that row

  if(coinFlip){
    cols <- grep("Pos.3", colnames(dataMatrix))
    dataMatrix[i, cols] <- dataMatrix[i, cols] + 3
  }

}

for(i in 1:40){
  # flip a coin
  coinFlip1 <- rbinom(1,size=1,prob=0.5)
  coinFlip2 <- rbinom(1,size=1,prob=0.5)
  # if coin is heads add a common pattern to that row
  if(coinFlip1){
    cols <- grep("Neg.15", colnames(dataMatrix))
    dataMatrix[i, cols] <- dataMatrix[i, cols] - 15
  }

  if(coinFlip2){
    cols <- grep("Pos.15", colnames(dataMatrix))
    dataMatrix[i,cols] <- dataMatrix[i,cols] + 15
  }
}
```

This generates a simple heatmap with an obvious pattern (the column names indicate the pattern)

[image: Heatmap of dataMatrix]

After I run the matrix through the svd() function I do a barplot of the V column to examine the values:

```
svd_out <- svd(scale(dataMatrix))

library(lattice)
key <- simpleKey(rectangles = TRUE, space = "top", points=FALSE,
          text=c("Positive", "Negative"))
key$rectangles$col <- c("steelblue", "darkred")

barchart(as.table(svd_out$v[,1]),
         horizontal=FALSE, col=ifelse(svd_out$v[,1] > 0, 
                                      "steelblue", "darkred"),
         ylab="Impact value", 
         xlab="SVD - percentage explained by V column",
         scales=list(x=list(rot=55, labels=colnames(dataMatrix), cex=1.1)),
         key = key)
```

[image: First simulated V column]

In the plot above the first V column indicates a strong impact from the patterned variables in both directions. The plot below shows the second V column and here the maximum value is a column without a pattern - if we used the absolute value we would select a patterned column.

[image: Second simulated V column]

**To conclude**: In the lecture slides this line:

```
maxContrib <- which.max(svd_out$v[,2])
```

should probably be:

```
maxContrib <- which.max(abs(svd_out$v[,2]))
```

### Old example

*An example based on R code that was used in the lectures*

I've used a dataset from the course first assignment together with the Hmisc, lattice and mice package for exploring the issue. You can load the dataset here (although the data needs some data munging):

```
http <- "https://spark-public.s3.amazonaws.com/dataanalysis/loansData.rda"
con <- url(http)
load(con)
```

When looking at the first column vector of svd$v very few values are negative:

```
numvars <- names(loansData)[sapply(loansData, is.numeric)]
# Don't use the outcome variable in any clustering/svd
numvars <- numvars[numvars %nin% c("interest_rate")]

library(mice)
imp <- mice(loansData[, numvars])
c_imp <- complete(imp)

svd_out <- svd(scale(c_imp))
perc_explained <- svd_out$d^2/sum(svd_out$d^2)

barchart(as.table(svd_out$v[,1]),
         horizontal=FALSE, col=ifelse(svd_out$v[,1] > 0, 
              "steelblue", "darkred"),
         ylab="Percentage explained", 
         xlab="SVD - percentage explained by V column",
         scales=list(x=list(rot=55, labels=label(loansData[, numvars]))))
```

[image: Red are negative while blue are positive values]

The same for the second column:

[image: Red are negative while blue are positive values]

When I selected the maximum contributor and any variable with at least 90 % of the maxcontributor function using the **which.max(abs())** the result seems about right:

[Using the absolute value for selecting contributors http://s3.postimage.org/t6kyrzn3m/Svd_abs_example.jpg](http://s3.postimage.org/t6kyrzn3m/Svd_abs_example.jpg)

and when I do with just the **which.max()** it looks rather suspicious:

[Without using the absolute value http://s4.postimage.org/k8vu343uj/Svd_non_abs_example.png](http://s4.postimage.org/k8vu343uj/Svd_non_abs_example.png)

As we see many maximum contributors are in multiple columns, while this may happen the amount of repetitiveness is not something that I would expect.

Here is the function that I've created to get the plot and the variables of interest:

```
getSvdMostInfluential <- function(mtrx, quantile, 
                                  show_selection=TRUE, 
                                  varnames=NULL, 
                                  similarityThreshold = 1){
  svd_out <- svd(scale(mtrx))
  perc_explained <- svd_out$d^2/sum(svd_out$d^2)
  cols_expl <- which(cumsum(perc_explained) < quantile)

  # Select the variables of interest
  vars <- list()
  for (i in 1:length(perc_explained)){
    v_abs <- svd_out$v[,i]
    maxContributor <- which.max(v_abs)
    similarSizedContributors <- which(v_abs >= v_abs[maxContributor]*.9)
    if (any(similarSizedContributors %nin% maxContributor)){
      maxContributor <- similarSizedContributors[order(v_abs[similarSizedContributors], decreasing=TRUE)]
    }
    vars[[length(vars) + 1]] <- maxContributor
  }

  if (show_selection){
    require(lattice)

    # Create transition colors
    selected_colors <- colorRampPalette(c("darkgreen", "#FFFFFF"))(length(perc_explained)+2)[1:length(cols_expl)]
    nonselected_colors <- colorRampPalette(c("darkgrey", "#FFFFFF"))(length(perc_explained)+2)[length(cols_expl)+1:length(perc_explained)]

    names <- unlist(lapply(vars, FUN=function(x){
      if (is.null(varnames)){
        varnames <- colnames(mtrx)
      }
      paste(varnames[x], collapse="\n")
    }))

    las <- 2
    m <- par(mar=c(8.1, 4.1, 4.1, 2.1))
    on.exit(par(mar=m))

    rotation <- 45 + (max(unlist(lapply(vars, length)))-1)*10
    if (rotation > 90)
      rotation <- 90
    p1 <- barchart(perc_explained ~ 1:length(perc_explained),
                   horiz=FALSE,
                   ylab="Percentage explained", 
                   xlab="SVD - percentage explained by V column",
                   col=c(selected_colors, nonselected_colors),
                   key=list(text=list(c("Selected", "Not selected")), 
                            rectangles=list(col=c("darkgreen", "#777777"))),
                   scales=list(x=list(rot=rotation, labels=names)))
    print(p1)
  }

  return(unique(unlist(vars)))
}

getSvdMostInfluential(c_imp, 0.8, varnames=label(loansData[, numvars]))
```

I've posted this question on the course forums but didn't get an answer. Note, this is not homework.

Comment: Dear @Max: Is that _statistical_ or _R_ language question? If you pose it as statistical then please show the _data_ and _describe_ what you did, instead of just showing R code which not one and all here understand.

Comment: @ttnphns: It is not an R question, I just used R to exemplify the problem as that is my stat-language of choice. The question is regarding how to interpret the V matrix of the SVD. As I'm not an expert and multiplying matrices I don't feel comfortable in just blatantly saying that prof. Leek was wrong in his notes. His interpretation of the SVD is really interesting and could be extremely useful - given that the logic isn't faulty. This could be perhaps a math question but I figured I start here as those answers often go beyond my mathematical skills...

Comment: @ttnphns: Tried to separate the two a little more.

Comment: Without a clear definition of degree of "contribution" this question looks unanswerable.  Is such a definition perhaps buried somewhere in the text or code, but I just missed it?  Regardless, the relevant definition from a purely mathematical view is to use the *squares* of the components.  The reason? Because, by the very construction of the SVD, the sums of squares of each row or of each column of $V$ are unity, whence the squares actually have a natural interpretation as a fraction of a whole.  Whether that's relevant to your *statistical* problem is a separate issue.